# what is meant by single level collation?

Tags: boost, internationalization, collation

In the [boost local documentation,](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/locale/doc/html/using_localization_backends.html) while discussing the tradeoffs involved in non-icu backends, one of the negatives is listed as:

> Collation, with exception of the winapi backend, is limited to a single level, similar to what is done by strcoll

What does this mean concretely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I continued my Unicode education, I discovered what is meant by collation levels, which are documented in [Unicode TR10](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Multi_Level_Comparison)

Unicode defines 5 collation levels:

1. L1: Base characters: role < roles

   L2: Accents:  role < rôle < roles

   L3: Case/Variants: role < Role < rôle

   L4: Punctuation: role < “role” < Rol

   Ln: Identical: role < ro□le < “role”